# Having Trouble Passing And Recieving Data From My Intent

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to make a pretty simple app to help my girlfriend feel safer.
Im really bad at this, and a little help would go a long way. I've been trying to work with intents, and I really feel as if I'm super close to the solution at hand, I just need a little help.

So, the opening page is supposed to wait until you have data in your shared Preferences and then it will act on it.

The second page is supposed to take some data from EditTexts and store it in your intent. For some reason though, my data is not being stored, and when I pull something from the intent it is "".

CLASS 1:

```
public void ActivateAlarm(View view){
        Bundle myBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(myBundle == null){
            Log.i("The bundle is empty!", "Smashing success!");
        }

        else{
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.jackson.distressalarm", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String NumberToCall = sharedPreferences.getString("CallNumber", "");
            String TextOne = sharedPreferences.getString("1Text", "");
            String TextTwo = sharedPreferences.getString("2Text", "");
            String TextThree = sharedPreferences.getString("3Text", "");


            Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            myButton.setText(TextOne);

            Log.i("MY NUMBER TO CALL", NumberToCall);
            /*Take in the data from the settings. Check it for consistency.
            1)Are the numbers empty?
            2)Is the number 911 or a 7 digit number?
            3)Do they have a passcode?
            4)Is the number real? No philisophical BS
             */
        }

    }
```

CLASS 2:

```
public void GoToAlarm(View view){

        EditText NumberToCall = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.callNumber);
        EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textNumOne);
        EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textNumTwo);
        EditText text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textNumThree);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmActive.class);

        intent.putExtra("callNumber", NumberToCall.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("1Text", text1.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("2Text", text2.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("3Text", text3.getText().toString());


        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is coming from a bit of a mix-up between `Intent`s and `SharedPreferences`.

An `Intent` is a way to pass data from one activity to another. You're passing data correctly in Class 2, but you're not retrieving it in Class 1. Here's how you can do that:

```
        String NumberToCall = intent.getStringExtra("CallNumber");
        String TextOne = intent.getStringExtra("1Text");
        String TextTwo = intent.getStringExtra("2Text");
        String TextThree = intent.getStringExtra("3Text");
```

`SharedPreferences` are a way to save user data. If you want to save data in addition to passing it between activities, you'll need to add it to `SharedPreferences` with the following code:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.jackson.distressalarm", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

editor.putString("callNumber", NumberToCall.getText().toString());
editor.putString("1Text", text1.getText().toString());
editor.putString("2Text", text2.getText().toString());
editor.putString("3Text", text3.getText().toString());

editor.apply();
```

You can retrieve the values with the code you were using in Class 1.

Comment: Awesome. So can the editor be accessed from any class? Or do I need to put the Strings from the editor into the intent and pass it to the first class?

Comment: Yes - SharedPreferences can be accessed from any activity with  `this.getSharedPreferences`. If you're starting out and you need example code or tutorials, the [Android developer training website](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) is a great resource. Check out [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) about SharedPreferences for example. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: So I think the app would work better if I took data from the SharedPreferences and put it into the the intent, but im having a tad bit of trouble.

Comment: This is how I think it should be, but it says this is invalid. What would be an example line to do this?

Comment: intent.putExtra("myCall", preferences.getString("callNumber"));

Comment: preferences.getString("callNumber") needs a second argument -- a default value if a preference by the name of "callNumber" is not found. You can probably just use an empty string: preferences.getString("callNumber", ""). This is described in the SharedPreferences [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).